# How to make one RxPath from two

Tags: xpath

I have those two RxPaths which I need to be written in one expresion:

```
/td[2]/a[1]/tag[1]
```

and

```
/td[2]/a[1]
```

So basically I need to select path with 'tag' element if exists, if not than to select 'a' element.
something like:

```
if exist /td[2]/a[1]/tag[1] select /td[2]/a[1]/tag[1]
else select /td[2]/a[1]
```

Those elements need to have innertext attribute with some value in them, so I tried:

```
/td[2]/descendant::node()[@innertext!='']
```

but it won't work...

Also those elements are at the bottom of hierarchy so if is there any way to just select first element at lowest level.

I managed to solve this with an regex at the end of my Xpath expression.

```
/dom/body/div[@id='isc_0']/div/div[@id='isc_B']/div[@id='isc_C']/div[@id='isc_10']/div/div/iframe/body/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/a[@innertext='any uri item']/../../td[2]/*[@innertext~'[^ ]+']
```

Sorry for misunderstanding with problem...

Regards,

Vajda Vladimir

Comment: Good question (never ask three questions at once!), +1. See my answer for simple one-liner XPath expressions as solutions to your first two questions. The third question is not clear -- better ask it as a separate question and specify well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So basically I need to select path
>   with 'tag' element if exists, if not
>   than to select 'a' element. something
>   like:
>
> if exist
>
> ```
>   /td[2]/a[1]/tag[1]
> ```
>
> select
>
> ```
>  /td[2]/a[1]/tag[1]
> ```
>
> else select
>
> ```
>   /td[2]/a[1]
> ```

---

**I highly doubt that the top element of the document is a `td`.** Don't use `/td` -- it means you want to select the top element of the document and this top element must be a `td` .

Also, `/td[2]` never selects anything, because a (wellformed) XML document has exactly one top element.

**Use**:

```
  someParentElement/td[2]/a[1]/tag[1] 
| 
  someParentElement/td[2]/a[1][not(someParentElement/td[2]/a[1]/tag[1])]
```

---

> Those elements need to have innertext
>   attribute with some value in them

**Use**:

```
  someParentElement/td[2][.//@innertext[normalize-space()]]/a[1]/tag[1] 
| 
  someParentElement/td[2]
              [.//@innertext[normalize-space()]]/a[1]
                  [not(someParentElement/td[2]
                       [.//@innertext[normalize-space()]]/a[1]/tag[1])]
```

---

> Also those elements are at the bottom
>   of hierarchy so if is there any way to
>   just select first element at lowest
>   level.

This is not clear. Please, clarify.

**All "leaf" elements can be selected using the following XPath expression**:

```
//*[not(*)]
```

The elements selected don't have any children-elements, but may have other children (such as text-nodes, PIs, comments) and attributes.

Comment: Yes, you are right when you say that td element is not top element, I just havent written all path because to simplify problem. Full path looks like this:
/dom[@domain='192.168.177.3:9080']/body/div/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td[@innertext='Presentation View']/../../../../../.././/a[@innertext='any uri item']/../../td[2]/a[1]
and all this with /tag et the end for second element

Comment: About bottom of hierarchy, those elements in that case don't contain any other element, they are leafs in some tree structure, they don't have children.

Comment: @Vajda: What are "those elements" you are talking about? please, *name* them.Is the question about selecting the "bottom" elements totally unrelated to the other two questions?

Comment: @Vajda: I added to my answer an XPath expression that selects all "leaf" elements -- is that what you wanted?

Comment: @Vajda: You just need to substitute in my answer  `someParentElement` with `/dom[@domain='192.168.177.3:9080']/body/div/div/div/div/table/tbody/`

Comment: Yes, that is all one problem, I just tried to make it easy for you to write Xpath, you can either choose one criteria. I solved this by adding regex at the end of my Xpath:
//*[@innertext~'[^ ]+']
So the whole path looks like this now:
/dom[@domain='192.168.177.3:9080']/body/div/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td[@innertext='Presentation View']/../../../../../.././/a[@innertext='any uri item']/../../td[2]//*[@innertext~'[^ ]+']
Sorry for not being clear enough.

Comment: @Vajda: But this is not syntactically legal XPath at all? Any language processor that accepts such expression is not XPath (1.0 or 2.0) - compliant.

Comment: @Vajda: Also, it seems that you are unaware of one important SO rule: The asker is expected *to accept* the answer that was most helpful. Accepting an answer is done by clicking on the green check-mark next to it.

Comment: @Dimitre: I wrote in my question that this it is not an XPath, but RxPath, language based on Xpath. Since I cannot create new tag named RxPath I used one the most similar -> XPath

Comment: @Vajda: You are welcome. I also tagged the question as rxpath. A new tag can be created very simply: just point the cursor right to the list of tags for the question and click on "edit tags". Then enter the name of any new desired tag -- it doesn't have to exist in SO.

Answer (score 0):

Besides all those good advices from @Dimitre, I want to add that a parent will always come before (in document order) than a child, so you could use this XPath expression:

```
(/real-path-from-root/td[2]/a[1] 
 | 
 /real-path-from-root/td[2]/a[1]/tag[1])[last()]
```

You could do this without `|` union set operator in XPath 1.0, but it will end up very unreadable... Of course, in XPath 2.0 you could just do:

```
(/real-path-from-root/td[2]/a[1]/(.|tag[1]))[last()]
```

Comment: Well, I need to do it without union because I only use concatenation to append original Xpath expression, so it should be appended to original one like you did in XPath 2.0 example